# How do I add a term reference name to the Pathauto pattern for a content type?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

I'm trying to create a website with 2 sections, Home and Business. For this I have created a vocabulary called '**Page Type**' and added those section names to it.

I've added a term reference field to my content type to relate nodes to my vocabulary.

What I need to do is automatically set the titles of the nodes to include the section name they are related to, using the Pathauto module.

I'm at the settings page (`/admin/config/search/path/patterns`) but I don't know what pattern to use - '**Page Type**' is a vocabulary, not a content type, so I don't know how to use it as part of a pattern.

How do I add the name of the referred taxonomy term to the node path? For example, I'm expecting URLs like this:

- example.com/home/page-title
- example.com/business/page-title

So I want the node page to have a vocabulary in its path, the vocabulary of a term it is tagged with.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you do not want to use the pattern for the content type but use the vocab to include in the url to access the node of the same content type as with the vocab? I'm asking because you can actually set the same path to be example.com/home/page-title using only the pattern from the path auto, for the content types. Is there any reason why you are duplicating this?

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like [node:field-yourfieldname].

On that page underneath each conten-type field, do you not see a "Replacement patterns" title?

If not, install the [token module](https://www.drupal.org/project/token).